# Content Security Policy: Allow files after initial load?

Tags: content-security-policy

The Content-Security-Policy header is, in theory, awesome. In practice, I've run into a problem. If a page loads the CSP and later you, for example, load a login page dynamically, the JS files for that page must have already been included. Because even if the login page uses an absolute URL which matches the domain the index page is from (And is set in the CSP for script-src), it will prevent it from loading.

When I used a nonce to try to circumvent this, the same issue arose, but it was intermittent. Sometimes it would let the same-nonce javascript file load in, and sometimes it wouldn't.

In case it's unclear, the dynamically-loaded script triggers CSP's idea of an "unsafe-inline script."

Is there a 100% effective way to load dynamic JS/CSS files with a strong CSP?

Freeform code example:

index.php:

```
<?php Header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://example.com"); ?>
<script src="triggerLogin.js"></script>
<a href="login.php" class="loginLink">Login</a>
<div class="futureLoginPage"></div>
```

triggerLogin.js: (CSP Allows)

```
$('.loginLink').on('click', function(event)
{
    $('.futureLoginPage').load('/login.php');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

login.php:

```
<script src="https://example.com/loginFormVerify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" class="user" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="text" class="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="button" class="send" value="Send" />
<div class="authStatus"></div>
```

loginFormVerify.js: (CSP Forbids)

```
$('.send').on('click', function()
{
    post("/verification.php", { user: $('.user').val(), pass: $('.pass').val() }, function(data)
    {
        $('.authStatus').html(data);
    });
});
```

It doesn't matter if I use https://example.com/ in the 'post' functions, as CSP doesn't even load the loginFormVerify.js file, let alone check its contents.

In reverse, it doesn't matter if I remove https://example.com/ from the JS script sources to let it resolve to its own understanding of the domain. It still fails.

It doesn't matter if I add type="text/javascript" or type="application/javascript" to one or both of the tags, either. And as mentioned above, a nonce only intermittently helps on a dynamically-loaded JS file sent from the server.

While we're at it, it doesn't matter if I have ' ' around the domain name in the header.

Also, I can remove the </script> tags and use the below to the exact same result:

```
<script src="..." />
```

I've attempted the above connection style on Safari, Chrome and Firefox with identical results. Safari and Chrome on mobile as well.

I'm aware one workaround is to condense all JS functionality into a single file at the index.php level, but I'm curious if there's a way to handle this some other way.

- I make no guarantees that the above example code works in any capacity and recognize the above snippet is far from best practice.
- The point of the above code is exclusively to provide an example of how CSP fails to provide a desired result in a dynamic environment, for the purposes of the question:

Is there a 100% effective workaround without reducing CSP's useful nature, other than preloading all scripts (Which can be harmful to speed, maintenance, bandwidth, and -- for those that care -- SEO)?

Comment: I think you're going to need a working example of this...I've never had a problem dynamically loading javascript with CSP unless the dynamically loaded CSP was violating the CSP. CSP applies equally to all resources loaded. You can test this by adding a resources with devtools and seeing it get blocked/allowed based on CSP.

If the issue's just unsafe inline loading the JS via an allowed JS file should work, or a sha hash if it's always the same inline code.

Comment: @BenBrocka Then I'm not sure why I'm having an issue, because I explained in thorough detail all the routes I've gone to try to work around it, and the results I get -- which is always the same result. And as mentioned in the post, nonce works intermittently, not 100% of the time. The example used is pretty much the real-world equivalent: Trying to use a file and CSP rejects it regardless of what I do to align it with CSP. The first-load files work fine, but any dynamically-added (Non-redirect) files are rejected.